# Why Clyde P. / Boeing B-52H Stratofortress flight from 1962 took the longer route?

Tags: aviation-history

Third on list of [longest non-stop, non-commercial powered aircraft's flights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_distance_record#Non-commercial_powered_aircraft) is January 10–11, 1962 flight on Boeing B-52H Stratofortress made by major Clyde P. Evely and crew. Can anyone provide any details about this flight?

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_distance_record#Non-commercial_powered_aircraft), that it was a flight from Japan (Okinawa) to Spain, via Tokyo, Seattle, Fort Worth, Washington and Azores. I'm especially interested in knowing, why that way? Most (all) of today commercial flights are flying Europe to Japan / Far East the opposite way, that is through Asia.

Is there any source of information, why did that flight took the longer route? Was that specially made to break the world record or was there any other circumstances to take such decision?

Comment: Would that shorter route have been overflying the USSR and/or the PRC?  In 1962, a B-52 doing that *might* have been poorly received...

Comment: Well... that could be a good point!

Comment: relevant: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14920

Comment: The B52 was not going to go that far without mid-air refueling, that route ensured that there was mid-air refueling available, and plenty of friendly places to land in case of trouble.

Comment: @GdD Cited [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_distance_record#Non-commercial_powered_aircraft) have in first paragraph a notice saying: "_This list of flight distance records contains only those set **without** any mid-air refueling_" (emphasis mine). I don't know nothing about "friendly places to land", but in conjuction with Ralph's comment this could be the point.

Comment: I remember in 1991 taking a direct flight from London to Tokyo over the USSR.  AIUI the ability to do that was new; 12 months before a previous group on the same trip had used a longer route over the Pole.

Comment: @NigelHarper It's also a little easier to get permission to fly a passenger airliner over another nation than it is to get permission to fly a B-52 over it...

Comment: @reirab Exactly. And if it was only just possible to get permission for commercial flights to overfly the USSR in 1991 it shows just how impossible it would've been to get the same for military craft 30 years previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The B-52 Stratofortress is a military jet, and specifically a US military jet, which if flown over USSR was very much in risk of being harmed. Thus, it was an intelligent decision to follow a longer route, rather than being a victim of ongoing cold war, following the longer route could have also helped the crew in achieving the longest flight record. Secondly, the B-52 did not have a very good [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress#Notable_accidents) even before 1962, thus taking precautions was a necessity for the crew, and they did this by choosing to fly over more helpful nations.  Also, aviation was not developed very much in Asia back in 1962 with very few strips of a large distance, to be used in case of emergency.

For more information, you may refer [this](http://www.thisdayinaviation.com/tag/clyde-p-evely/) and [this](http://www.minotdailynews.com/page/content.detail/id/519514.html?nav=5576)!

Comment: The B-52 _is_ a military jet. It's still very much in service today. It's one of the longest-serving military aircraft in history, especially for a jet.

Comment: Saying that the B-52 would have been at risk of being harmed if it overflew the USSR is something of an understatement. Doing that might have started World War III.

Comment: Okay , then as @RalphJ says, it would at least have been poorly received.